# I want to change the background colors using DAX measure in conditional formatting

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am new to DAX and wanted solution for the following report.

[Data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21bWD.jpg)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAL0f.jpg)

I want to change the background color using DAX measure in conditional formatting in my report.
The lookup column is "Column2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is inbuilt in Power bi.

### Method 1

1. Select the table
2. in the menu select Conditional formatting

[image]

3. Pick the column

[image]

4. Turn on the Background color and click on Advance control

[image]

5. Configure the fields as follows

- From the drop down menu Formatted by choose Rules
- For base on fields pick the column again from the drop down
- For summarization pick average
- In the rules create the rules that you required
- Add a new rule click on **+ New Rule** button

[image]

### Method 2

Create below measure

```
COLOUR EQUAL ROW = 
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'DIM Hospital'[hospital_id] ),
    IF (
        MAX ( 'DIM Hospital'[hospital_id] ) <= 2,
        "lightgreen",
        IF (
            MAX ( 'DIM Hospital'[hospital_id] ) <= 5,
            "blue",
            IF ( MAX ( 'DIM Hospital'[hospital_id] ) <= 20, "orange", "white" )
        )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

For configuring please choose the respective column and configure the formatting as below.

[image]

Sample below.
[image]

Comment: @Sushma Checkout the method 2

Comment: Thanks Amila for the steps. But I have already done this and got the expected output. But they are asking me to create the same output using DAX measure. I have tried the following measure:  Measure 2 = 
VAR q =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table 1'[1/1/2021])
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        q <= 2 "Yellow", 
        q >=3,q<=4 "BLUE",
        q >=5, q<=20 "Orange"
                                                                                           
    )

Comment: Question is bit unclear.